# Native Compile java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.<init>() exception for apache-poi

Tags: java, gradle, apache-poi, log4j, graalvm

I have a little java application with `picocli` and `apache-poi`:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.10.1'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'info.picocli:picocli:4.7.5'
    annotationProcessor 'info.picocli:picocli-codegen:4.7.5'

    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5')
    implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.5')
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Aproject=${project.group}/${project.name}"]
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.example.NativeCompileExample'
}
```

NativeCompileExample.java

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPrintSetup;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import picocli.CommandLine;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

@CommandLine.Command(
        name = "example",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        description = "example description")
public class NativeCompileExample implements Callable<Integer> {

    @CommandLine.Parameters(description = "The input file")
    private File inputFile;

    @CommandLine.Parameters(description = "The output file")
    private File outputFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final int exitCode = new CommandLine(new NativeCompileExample()).execute(args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        try (final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputFile)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                sheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);
                sheet.getPrintSetup().setPaperSize(HSSFPrintSetup.A4_PAPERSIZE);
            }

            workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I compile the application with native-compile via gradle with graalvm-21 (installed via sdkman. Version `21.0.2-graalce`):

```bash
./gradlew clean build nativeCompile
```

When I run the compiled application, I see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:601)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:601)
        at com.example.NativeCompileExample.call(NativeCompileExample.java:37)
        at com.example.NativeCompileExample.call(NativeCompileExample.java:18)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at com.example.NativeCompileExample.main(NativeCompileExample.java:31)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:239)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.<init>(AbstractLogger.java:138)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<init>(StatusLogger.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:91)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:719)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:237)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.<init>()
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1075)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1238)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:706)
        ... 20 more
```

When running the application without native-compile it, it works.
I assume it has something to do with the fact that log4j is not supported by graalvm.

Any tips how I can tell apache-poi to use something different or just provide an empty implementation for the logging classes?

I tried to exclude `log4j-api` from the `apache-poi` dependencies via gradle:

```
implementation('org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
}
implementation('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.5') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
}
```

But then ofcourse the error was not gone because now `apache-poi` complains that classes are missing.

I also tried to add `log4j-over-slf4j` but it provides different packages as used by `apache-poi`:

- in `log4j-over-slf4j` the package structure is `org.apache.log4j.*`
- `apache-poi` uses the log classes from the following package: `org.apache.logging.log4j.*`

Comment: how did you generate your reflect jsons? check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71147190/175554) for how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue (cf. [Issue #1539](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1539)) due to the way Log4j 2.x instantiates message factories, which is apparently not supported by GraalVM.

The issue is addressed in [PR #2392](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/2392) for the `java.util.logging` and Logback backend of Log4j API.

Log4j Core users currently need to generate reachability configuration themselves. There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/discussions/2364) on what kind of reachability metadata should be shipped with `log4j-core` by default.

### Workaround

The core of the problem is that libraries such as Log4j Core and Logback transform configuration files into a tree of Java components using reflection.

Since the reflective calls don't have compile-time constant arguments, GraalVM is not able to determine which classes need to be included.

To workaround this you can add a **reachability configuration** to your application (cf. [reachability metadata](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/)).

The easiest way to do this is to:

- run your application using Java and GraalVM's tracing agent (cf. [tracing agent](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/)). The tracing agent will detect all the classes that are accessed through reflection and will create the necessary `reflect-config.json` and `resources-config.json` configuration files.
- copy the generated `*-config.json` files into a `META-INF/native-image/<group.id>/<artifact.id>` resource folder of your application,
- compile the application using GraalVM.

Comment: So I can not compile my programm with graalvm because a thrid-party lib uses log4j?

Comment: @ppfeiler: I have added some instructions on how to add the necessary GraalVM **reachability configuration**, that will allow your application to compile. Can you describe your use case in the [Log4j GraalVM Github discussion](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/discussions/2364)?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Adding the "shade" plugin and running the tracing agent did the trick. 

Now I am stuck on the "Defining hidden classes at runtime is not supported" exception, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673595/graalvm-native-image-and-log4j-causing-error-defining-hidden-classes-at-runtim.

I will late take a look at the Github discussion.

Comment: The call to `LambdaMetaFactory` was introduced in version 2.19.0 to support both JPMS and SecurityManager (cf. [PR #1008](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/1008)). You can downgrade to 2.18.0 to work around that.

Comment: Thank you! I had to downgrade to 2.17.0 but now it seems that everything is working.

Comment: If you also use `log4j-core`, use version 2.17.1 or later, since previous versions have CVEs.

Comment: I had the same issue today and can confirm that generating reflect-config.json and resource-config.json + downgrading to 2.18.0 works!